# Why does laravel passport revoke my auth code during the second request

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

So I followed the documentation in laravel passport and created new client by doing this

```
const redirectToAuthorization = (clientId, redirectUri) => {
    const state = Math.random().toString(36).substring(7);
    const queryParams = new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: clientId,
        redirect_uri: redirectUri,
        response_type: "code",
        scope: "",
        state: state,
    });
    return (window.location.href = `http://localhost:5001/oauth/authorize?${queryParams.toString()}`);
};
```

This in turn redirects me to my callback url

```
http://localhost:3000/callback?code=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&state=i2qnf
```

This in turn prompts me the user to authorize

So after authorization, I use the auth code to get access token.

[image]

During the first request, I was able to get the access token and refresh token

But during the second request, I was NOT able to get access token and refresh token. Instead I got this error

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed.",
    "hint": "Authorization code has been revoked",
    "message": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed."
}
```

So my question is how do I get a new auth code ?